# Why I put a for loop inside a function cannot work?

Tags: python

here is my code
I am wondering why i cannot put a 'for loop' into a function

```
>>> a=[5,3,5,6,8,9,0,1,3]
>>> def classification(input):
        scoreget=0
        for i in range(0,8):
            if input[i]>2:
                 scoreget+=1
            else:
                 scoreget+=0
            return scoreget
>>> result=classification(a)
>>> print result
```

The result should be [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1], but it showed only one value '1',not a set.

Comment: You're returning after the first iteration of the for loop.

Comment: `return` should be outside of `for`. Plus `scoreget` should be a list not an integer, else it will return 7

Comment: Delete one tabspace before `return scoreget`

Comment: sorry,the result should be a value which is a quantity of a element which is bigger than 2, so it should be 7, but not 1

Comment: thanks a lot,it works

Answer (score 1):

The way functions work in Python is that first the entire for loop is done and next the output of the function is returned. In this case that means that only the last output is returned. Also your range doesn't cover all the input parameters, which can be resolved using len. Below is an example of your code which would work:

```
a = [5, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3]
def classification(inputs):
    scoreget = 0
    score = []
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        if inputs[i] > 2:
             scoreget = 1
        else:
             scoreget = 0
        score.append(scoreget)
    return score

    result = classification(a)
```

print result

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion is very helpful for me.